# cl.exe installed but not found

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, cl

I've looked at the other questions on this, all say install visual studio with c++, I have done this - 2017 version.
I'm trying to build pypoisson in python3 which requires the c++ complier, I get this error:

```
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include "-IC:\Pr
ogram Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x8
6)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\pypoisson.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pypoisson.obj -w -fopenmp
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

I looked in my system variables and in path there is a route to cl.exe

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe`

and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin`

My system is 64-bit OS and x64-based processor

Searching windows for cl.exe returns 8 possibilities all under the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin` some in Hostx64 and Hostx86

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for months.

# EDIT

On running:pip install git+https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson.git

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson.git
  Cloning https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson.git to c:\users\garyn\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mp9rv8zh
Installing collected packages: pypoisson
  Running setup.py install for pypoisson ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\garyn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-mp9rv
8zh\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\garyn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z9a0hu
hl\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include\site\python3.7\pypoisson:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    cythoning src/pypoisson.pyx to src\pypoisson.cpp
    C:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a la
ter release! File: C:\Users\garyn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-mp9rv8zh\src\pypoisson.pyx
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    warning: src\pypoisson.pyx:130:67: Index should be typed for more efficient access
    building 'pypoisson' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\PoissonRecon_v6_13
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\PoissonRecon_v6_13\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib
\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\W
indows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\pypoisson.cpp /Fobuild
\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pypoisson.obj -w -fopenmp
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
    pypoisson.cpp
    c:\users\garyn\pycharmprojects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPREC
ATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib
\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\W
indows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src
/CmdLineParser.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/CmdLineParser.obj -w -fopenmp
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
    CmdLineParser.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib
\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\W
indows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src
/Factor.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Factor.obj -w -fopenmp
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
    Factor.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\lib
\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\garyn\PycharmProjects\pointcloudprocessor\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\W
indows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src
/Geometry.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/PoissonRecon_v6_13/src/Geometry.obj -w -fopenmp
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
    Geometry.cpp
    c:\users\garyn\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mp9rv8zh\src\poissonrecon_v6_13\src\Geometry.h(33): fatal error C1189: #error:  OpenMP is required
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: You can't just run it from the command line. [Top hit on google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Try `path %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64` in the cmd.exe session before starting cl.exe

Comment: @super You most certainly *can* run the compiler from Visual Studio (`cl.exe`) from the command line.

Comment: Thanks harper for the suggestion, but it doesn't change the end result.
I'm running in the terminal of pycharm:
git clone --recursive git://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson.git
python setup.py build <this is where the problem arises>
python setup.py install

Comment: @JesperJuhl The link I posted describes how to do it, maybe a bit unclear but **just** here means you need more then just start `cmd.exe` and run `cl.exe`.

Comment: @super thank you for trying to help, unfortunately the instructions are unclear. pypoisson is located here https://github.com/mmolero/pypoisson I can download it, but where do I go from here seeing that the pip install options fail due to the cl.exe issue ?

Comment: @GaryNobles With your update, it says `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'`. I would try to edit setup.py to use `extra_link_args=["/openmp"]` instead of `-fopenmp`. Same thing for compile args as well.

Comment: @super, I altered the setup.py, there were two with the compile parameters, I'm not sure what openmp is meant to be or where to find it, I'll keep investigating the file.